# How to extract x and y from a coordinate pair using regex

Tags: python, regex, string, math

How would I use regex to extract a and b from (a,b)?

For example:

```
string = "(1,-5)"
string = "(0, \infty)"
```

And then the output would be:

```
x = 1
y = -5


x = 0
y = \infty
```

Please note that this needs to work with more than just integers, but strings as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function :

```
>>> string = "(1,-5)"
>>> map(int,re.findall(r'-?\d',string))
[1, -5]
```

The pattern `\d` will match any digits in your string!

Comment: But will this work if the coordinates are in scientific notation (with an e)?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor no it doesn't ! OP doesn't mentioned this point!

Answer (score 2):

you can use `ast.literal_eval` instead of regex:

```
>>> import ast
>>> my_string = "(1,-5)"
>>> x,y = ast.literal_eval(my_string)
>>> x
1
>>> y
-5
```

if you bother about scientific notation, then yes it will work:

```
>>> my_string = "(1.2e3,-5.56)"
>>> x,y = ast.literal_eval(my_string)
>>> x
1200.0
>>> y
-5.56
```

Answer (score 2):

This will be tricky with a regular expression, since the syntax of numbers can include non-digits.  E.g., `3.8e8` is a legal number, but has a `.` and an `e`:

```
>>> 3.8e8
380000000.0
```

This means that regular expressions with `\d` won't work:

```
>>> re.findall('\d','(1.2e3,4.5e6)')
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```

It may be better to just *split* the string on the comma and then remove the parentheses:

```
>>> def coords(string):
...   x, _, y = string.partition(',')
...   return x.lstrip('('), y.rstrip(')')
... 
>>> coords('(123,456)')
('123', '456')
```

Of course, that's fragile too, because there could be whitespace in there, etc.  It's tough to handle input if you don't have a concrete specification of what's legal and what's not.

If you expect it to be legal Python input, though;  it may be best to just use the literal_eval, as suggested in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28637986/1281433).

Answer (score 1):

The old joke

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think
>   "I know, I'll use regular expressions."   Now they have two problems.

I don't recommend using a regex, I'm just posting this for fun.

```
import re
matcher = re.compile('\(\s*([+-]?\d+(\.\d+(e[+-]?\d+)?)?)\s*,\s*([+-]?\d+(\.\d+(e[+-]?\d+)?)?)\s*\)')
result = matcher.match('(  +4.5e-4, -5.4e+4  )')
x = float(result.group(1)) #       0.00045
y = float(result.group(4)) #  -54000.0
```

**PS.** I like the split and strip solution that Joshua Taylor posted.

Comment: I like the spirit of the "use regex anyways" (esp. with the acknowledgment that there are limitations), but this won't handle scientific notation, will it? E.g., `1.2e3`?  And remember that there can be signs on all the parts, e.g., `-2.3e-4 ==> -0.00023`.

Comment: Ok fixed it, happy now :)

Answer (score 0):

`?` means 0 or 1, `\d` means digit, `+` means one or more. `\.` matches dot (since `.` is a special character without a backslash), `*` means 0 or more.

```
my_string = '(1,-52.42)'
x, y = re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d*', my_string)

print(x, y)
```

Comment: Will this work with scientific notation (e.g., with an e in the middle)?

Comment: Nope, since the example didnt have it. I can adjust it though.