# How to read user input containing coordinates in parenthesis

Tags: python, input

I am making a really simple game where you make a table of numbers and hide a bomb that the user needs to find.

Here is the code:

```
import random
def game(rows, colums):   
    table = (rows * colums - 1) * [' '] + ['bomb']    
    random.shuffle(table)    
    while True:    
        position = input('Enter next position (x, y):')    
        bombposition = position.split()    
        if table[int(bombposition[0])*colums + int(bombposition[1])] == 'bomb':    
            print('you found the bomb!')    
            break    
        else:    
            print('no bomb at', position)
```

the error:

```
game(1,0)    
Enter next position (x, y):>?    
(1,0)    
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "input", line 1, in <module>   
  File "input", line 8, in game    
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '(1,0)'
```

Comment: You will receive this error when your trying to pass a float/string through an integer

Comment: @Barb It has nothing to do with floats. As the error message said, they were effectively trying to call `int('(1,0)')`

Comment: Floats and strings. `.split` splits strings not integers..

Comment: Related: [How to extract x and y from a coordinate pair using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28637928/7851470).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly `split` uses whitespace by default, so to split on a comma you'd need `position.split(',')`. Although even then, your `split` will still have the `(` and `)` attached to your strings if you split on , for example in your case `'(1'` and `'0)'`. I'd suggest maybe using a regex to extract the numbers from your input

```
import re

position = input('Enter next position (x, y):') 
match = re.match(r'\((\d+)\, *(\d+)\)', position)
if match:
    x = int(match.group(1))
    y = int(match.group(2))
else:
    # input didn't match desired format of (x, y)
```

Comment: I am trying to make sense out of your answer but im having real trouble figuring it out :S

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the way you compute `bombposition`:

```
bombposition = position.lstrip("(").rstrip(")").split(",")
```

Comment: If I try your version I get this error:

"game(1,3)
Enter next position (x, y):>? (1,3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 7, in game
IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: @JeanSwanborn My solution is correct, your input is wrong! If a table has dimension rows*columns then the indexes you can use are 0...rows-1 and 0...columns-1. You can't have (x,y)==(1,3). Instead, you should use (x,y)==(0,2).